# Ordering jQuery functions or rotating an element at different speeds in the same program

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write a flashcards program. The user should have the ability to go to the next/previous card using the arrow keys and flip the card (by clicking or pressing the spacebar). The flip animation is done by css styling the card with:

```
transition: transform 0.8s;
```

Then, the flip animation is performed as follows:

```
if (flipped) {
  $('.card').css('transform', 'none');
} else {
  $('.card').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
}
```

The issue is that if the user is on the back of the card and presses the arrow key to go to the next card, I would like the user to see the FRONT of the next card. Essentially, if the card is flipped, I would like the card to flip over **in zero seconds instead of 0.8s** and then go to the next card.

So far I have tried something like:

```
function next_card() {
  if(flipped) {
      $('.card').css('transition', 'transform 0s')
                .css('transform', 'none')
                .css('transition', 'transform 0.8s');
  }
  // Go to next card
}
```

However, the program executes css('transition', 'transform 0.8s') before css('transform', 'none') making the code useless. I have tried to look into deferreds and promises as a way to ensure that the functions execute in the correct order but I am not a very experienced programmer and got confused about how to apply them to my situation.

**Edit: make a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bjfy3tmc/28/ to illustrate the issue. The problem is that when the user is on the back of a card and then goes to the next or previous card, the card should shown the FRONT of the next card and not see a flip animation at all.**

Comment: Toggle a class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] to see how to write a good question and create a [MRE] with the relevant code to show the problem.

Comment: `transform:none` Defines that there should be no transformation. If you are wanting to reverse the animation try setting it to `rotateY(0deg)`

Comment: @epascarello I tried that but adding and removing a class introduces the same problem with function order as I was having. Could you explain in more detail what you meant?

Comment: @Jasmine `transform: none` works the same as setting `rotateY(0deg)` and I have not had any problem doing it that way. Is there a reason `rotateY(0deg)` is better?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you and apologies for not asking my question as well as possible! I have included a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow the paint cycle to execute with the first CSS changes, so you will only reset the CSS to the 0.8 sec transformation *after* that has happened.

You can use `requestAnimationFrame` for that. The callback you pass will be executed just before the next repaint, which is still too early. But if you call `requestAnimationFrame` again within that callback, and pass it yet another callback, *that* callback will be scheduled to execute *after* the current repaint, and before the next, which is what you want.

So:

```
$('.card-inner').css('transition', 'transform 0s')
                .css('transform', 'none');
requestAnimationFrame(function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    $('.card-inner').css('transition', 'transform 0.8s');
  })
});
```

This still means that there is *one* frame where the next card is shown (with the back side). To also prevent that, put the rest of the code (which sets the front/end content) in an `else` block, and call `iter` a second time when it is sure that the new CSS is in effect:

```
function iter(x) {
  if($('.card-inner').css('transform') != 'none') {
    $('.card-inner').css('transition', 'transform 0s')
                    .css('transform', 'none');
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        iter(x);
        $('.card-inner').css('transition', 'transform 0.8s');
      })
    })
  } else if(index+x < front_cards.length && index+x >= 0) {
    $('.front').html(front_cards[index+x]);
    $('.back').html(back_cards[index+x]);
    index += x;
  }
}
```

Or, alternatively, *always* use the callback system to go to the next/prev card:

```
function iter(x) {
  if($('.card-inner').css('transform') != 'none') {
    $('.card-inner').css('transition', 'transform 0s')
                    .css('transform', 'none');
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      if(index+x < front_cards.length && index+x >= 0) {
        $('.front').html(front_cards[index+x]);
        $('.back').html(back_cards[index+x]);
        index += x;
      }
      $('.card-inner').css('transition', 'transform 0.8s');
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed and it is working perfectly.